# call_user_func() to validate array values

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I want to preset validation rules for fields via an array, such as:

```
$vals = array(
   'val1' => array(
       'rule' => 'ctype_alnum',
   ),
   'val2' => array(
       'rule' => 'ctype_digit',
   ),
);
```

These fields will be imported from a CSV and inserted into the database if they meet basic validation.

E.g

```
$while ($data = fgetcsv....)

$array['val1'] = $data[2];
$array['val2'] = $data[9];
$array['val3'] = $data[11];
```

What I want to do, and I'm not sure how to do this exactly, is now cross reference the `$array` array with the preset rules in the `$fields` array. If any of the fields don't validate then the import will be aborted for this row.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```
foreach ($vals as $key => $rule)
{

  if (function_exists($rule['rule']) && !call_user_func($rule['rule'], $array[$key]))
  {
    continue 2;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. So `continue 2` when validation rule is met for the current field in the iteration - will then skip on to next field. If I want to do a db insert if all fields in current array (csv row) are validated - would set a boolean outside of the foreach perhaps? If all fields validate, check boolean after foreach and update db

Comment: If any field doesn't validate, would break out of the foreach, do some admin email/logging for that row, then move onto next row

Comment: `continue 2` if a validation fails; that will skip to the next line of the CSV -- so just add the database insert beneath the `foreach ($vals as ...)`

Comment: Comment about "break" deleted, I misread question and code, sorry!

Comment: If you want to log the row on failure, put it before the `continue 2` line within the `if` block

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see, is that you have to determine how you are going to validate each column, for example, is column 0 being validated as an alphanumeric, or as a digit? Another approach, giving validation context to each column would look like:

```
$columnsDigit = array(0, 3, 7, 8);
$columnsAlnum = array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6);

$while ($line = fgetcsv....) {

    foreach ($line as $column => $value) {

        if ((in_array($column, $columnsDigit)) && (false === ctype_digit($value))) {
            continue 2;
        }

        elseif ((in_array($column, $columnsAlnum)) && (false === ctype_alnum($value))) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    // Do something with your valid line
 }
```